# Vb.net check if table exist in DB Mysql without Try Catch

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hello i want to find the best way for ask to Mysql if a table exist, i find many examples but all wait a exception with try catch like this

```
Try
      'do a select COUNT(*)
Catch ex as Exception
      'return True to indicate table exist
Finally 
     'clean up
End try
```

but i think no is a good method, well i repeat i think so, other method is this:

```
   Using cn As New MySqlConnection(cs)
            Dim restrictions(4) As String
            restrictions(2) = tblName
            Dim dbTbl As DataTable = cn.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions)
            If dbTbl.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                'Table does not exist
                Return False
            Else
                'Table exists
                Return True
            End If
            cn.Close()
            cn.Dispose()
```

but i have a message reference to an object not set.

Comment: I don't see where you are opening the connection. Also, where do you get the reference error? Which line?

Comment: the connection are good, no worry for that, the exception is in the line **dim dbtbl as datatable.....**

Comment: hold your mouse over the different object variables and see which one is `Nothing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** 
Mysql provide a method, i think is the best way excute this line

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema =  'Database'
AND table_name =  'Table'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this query and see if any results come back:

```
show tables like 'my-table-name';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by the fact the a connection should be opened before issuing commands. Your second example should work as is, if you just add that missing `cn.Open`

```
Using cn As New MySqlConnection(cs)
  Dim restrictions(4) As String
  restrictions(2) = tblName
  cn.Open()
  Dim dbTbl As DataTable = cn.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions)
  If dbTbl.Rows.Count = 0 Then
      Return False
  Else
     Return True
  End If
End Using
```

Also, there is no need to close and dispose the connection, this will be done automatically at the `End Using` statement. Of course, the first method trying to discover if the table exists catching an exception is totally wrong (performances, code driven by exceptions, other kind of exceptions) and should not be taken in any consideration.

There is a perplexing point in the code that uses the GetSchema call:
The message talks about a Null Reference Exception but apparently there are no null objects in that code because `GetSchema` is supposed to return an initialized `DataTable` also in case no match is found.
However if you omit that cn.Open you get the NRE.

So where is the NRE coming from?

Looking at the decompiled code of the MySqlConnection, the call to GetSchema is something like this

```
public override DataTable GetSchema(string collectionName, string[] restrictionValues)
{
    string[] strArray;
    MySqlSchemaCollection schemas;
    if (collectionName != null)
    {
        goto Label_000A;
    }
    collectionName = SchemaProvider.MetaCollection;
Label_000A:
    strArray = this.schemaProvider.CleanRestrictions(restrictionValues);
    return this.schemaProvider.GetSchema(collectionName, strArray).AsDataTable();
}
```

and the code called by `this.schemaProvider.GetSchema(....)` is the following

```
public virtual MySqlSchemaCollection GetSchema(string collection, string[] restrictions)
{
    MySqlSchemaCollection schemas;
    if (this.connection.State == 1)
    {
        goto Label_0019;
    }
    throw new MySqlException("GetSchema can only be called on an open connection.");
Label_0019:
    collection = StringUtility.ToUpperInvariant(collection);
    schemas = this.GetSchemaInternal(collection, restrictions);
    if (schemas != null)
    {
        goto Label_0038;
    }
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid collection name");
Label_0038:
    return schemas;
}
```

So this leaves only one possibility. The `schemaProvider` variable is not initialized. Searching the `Open` method of the `MySqlConnection` I could find the line that initializes the schemaProvider variable

```
public override void Open()
{
    ... lot of code omitted .....

Label_01F3:
    this.schemaProvider = new ISSchemaProvider(this);
    this.perfMonitor = new PerformanceMonitor(this);
    if ((Transaction.Current != null) == null)
    {
        goto Label_0230;
    }
    if (this.Settings.AutoEnlist == null)
    {
        goto Label_0230;
    }
    this.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current);
Label_0230:
    this.hasBeenOpen = 1;
    this.SetState(1, 1);
    return;
}
```

So it is possible that this is a bug of some kind?
I will let the answer to someone more expert on this.

Comment: If the connection is not opened, then `schemaProvider` would be null, so the NRE would happen in the first snippet for `GetSchema` (at the label)  - they are not checking if  `schemaProvider` is null before executing a method on it, no?

Comment: Yes, I think this should be considered a bug. But, of course I am not certain if that internal variable _schemaProvider_ is initialized in other ways. Another point that let me think that this is a bug, it is the fact that, if you use the con.GetSchema("TABLES") without the restrictions on a NOT opened connection, the call fails with the correct error message

Comment: It is definitely a bug in so far as the exception thrown is the generic NRE vs something more informative.  I get the same NRE using `dbCon.GetSchema("TABLES")`  (NET 4.5 connectors)